# Counting total occurrences of each 'version' across multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a number of files in a directory on Linux, each of which contains a `version` line in the format: `#version x` (where x is the version number).

I'm trying to find a way to count the number of times each different version appears across all the files, and output something like:

```
#version 1: 12
#version 2: 36
#version 3: 2
```

I don't know all the potential versions that might exist, so I'm really trying to match lines that contain `#version`.

I've tried using things like `grep -c` - however that only gives the total of all lines containing `#version` - I can't find a nice way to split on the different version numbers.

Comment: How do you get the above lines from the files? I don' think the tag `bash` applies to this que

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility piping multiple commands:

```
strings * | grep '#version \w' | sort | uniq --count | awk '{printf("%s: %s\n", substr($0, index($0, $2)), $1)}''
```

Operations breakdown:

- `strings *`: Extract text strings from `*` all files in current directory.
- `| grep '#version \w'`: Pipe the strings into the `grep` command, to find all occurrences of `#version word`.
- `sort`: Pipe the version strings to the `sort` command.
- `| uniq --count`: Pipe the occurrences of `#version` lines into the `uniq` command, to output count of each `#version...` string.
- `awk '{printf("%s: %s\n", substr($0, index($0, $2)), $1)}'`: Pipe the unique counts into the `awk` command, to re-format the output as: `#version ...: count`.

Testing the process:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir testing 2>/dev/null || true
cd testing
# Create 10 testfile#.txt with random #version 1 to 4
for i in {1..10}; do
 echo "#version $(($RANDOM%4+1))" >"testfile${i}.txt"
done
# Now get the counts per version
strings * \
  | grep '#version \w' \
  | sort \
  | uniq --count \
  | awk '{printf("%s: %s\n", substr($0, index($0, $2)), $1)}'
```

Example of test output:

```
#version 1: 4
#version 2: 2
#version 3: 1
#version 4: 3
```

Comment: Thanks for this - in the end the exact format wasn't critical, so I opted for the simpler: `grep -h '#version \w' * | sort |uniq --count` but accepting your answer as it was `uniq --count` that really solved it for me!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may do the trick:

```
grep -h '#version' * | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$3": found "$1}'
```

example files:

`filename:filecontent`

```
file1:#version 1
file1.1:#version 1
file111:#version 1
file2:#version 2
file3:#version 3
file4:#version 4
file44:#version 4
```

Output:

```
#version 1: found 3
#version 2: found 1
#version 3: found 1
#version 4: found 2
```

`grep version *` gets all files with version.`sort` sorts the results for `uniq -c` which counts the number of duplicates then `awk` rearranges the output for desired formatting.

Note: `grep` might have a slightly different separator than `:` on your OS.